# Python smart voice assistant with using a JSON file

Tags: python, audio, voice-recognition, google-assistant, pyttsx3

I was trying to create a voice assistant using python... but my code is showing some weird texts when I run it... down below is my code

```
from email.mime import audio
from logging.config import listen
import re
from neuralintents import GenericAssistant
import speech_recognition
import sys
import pyttsx3 as tts

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

speaker = tts.init()

speaker.setProperty('rate',150)

def create_note():
global recognizer

speaker.say("What do you want to say?")
speaker.runAndWait()

done=False

while not done:
    try:

        with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=0.2)
            audio= recognizer.listen(mic)

            note = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            note = note.lower()

            speaker.say("choose a file name")
            speaker.runAndWait

            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic, duration=.2)
            audio = listen(mic)

            filename = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            filename = filename.lower()


        with open(filename,'w' ) as f:
            f.write(note)
            done= True
            speaker.say={f"I saved the note {filename}"}
            speaker.runAndWait()


    except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
        recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
        speaker.say("I dont got that, please say it again")
        speaker.runAndWait()






mappings = {'greeting': create_note}

assitant = GenericAssistant('intents.json',intent_methods=mappings)
assitant.train_model()
```

I expect it to get the input from the mic then go through a JSON file and say the next thing according to the JSON file....
here is the contents of the JSON file

[JSON FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey7sv.png)